# what PID does os.killpg look for

Tags: python, subprocess

I am writing code to kill a process and all children processes.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true), all children processes can be killed within the same process group by using `os.killpg(pro.pid, signal.SIGTERM)`

During test, I launched this process manually which spawned 5 subprocesses.

```
    UID      PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
    ddd    25066 19475  0 Nov03 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c gtdownload -c ~/.cghub.key --max-children 4 -vv -d https://cghub.ucsc.edu/cghub/data/analysis/download/ab0e89b4-5310-11e4-88da-adc9fc308db6 2
    ddd    25067 25066  0 Nov03 ?        00:00:07 /rsrch1/rists/djiao/apps/cghub/libexec/gtdownload -c /rsrch1/rists/djiao/.cghub.key --max-children 4 -vv -d https://cghub.ucsc.edu/cghub/data/analysis/d
    ddd    25073 25067  0 Nov03 ?        00:00:18 /rsrch1/rists/djiao/apps/cghub/libexec/gtdownload -c /rsrch1/rists/djiao/.cghub.key --max-children 4 -vv -d https://cghub.ucsc.edu/cghub/data/analysis/d
    ddd    25077 25067  0 Nov03 ?        00:00:18 /rsrch1/rists/djiao/apps/cghub/libexec/gtdownload -c /rsrch1/rists/djiao/.cghub.key --max-children 4 -vv -d https://cghub.ucsc.edu/cghub/data/analysis/d
    ddd    25081 25067  0 Nov03 ?        00:00:18 /rsrch1/rists/djiao/apps/cghub/libexec/gtdownload -c /rsrch1/rists/djiao/.cghub.key --max-children 4 -vv -d https://cghub.ucsc.edu/cghub/data/analysis/d
    ddd    25085 25067  0 Nov03 ?        00:00:18 /rsrch1/rists/djiao/apps/cghub/libexec/gtdownload -c /rsrch1/rists/djiao/.cghub.key --max-children 4 -vv -d https://cghub.ucsc.edu/cghub/data/analysis/d
```

However when I ran os.killpg(25066, signal.SIGTERM), I got the error "OSError: [Errno 3] No such process". Why can't it find the process with that ID?

Comment: In the linked post, did you see how they called `Popen`? In particular, the `preexec_fn=os.setsid` is important.

Comment: I thought that step is just to initiate the process. Once it is started it will have a PID assigned anyway. In my real code I did use Popen with setsid. I just wanted to test the killpg first and see what it actually kills

Comment: `killpg` sends a signal to all of the processes in a process group, and takes a process group ID. `setsid` creates a new process group, with its id equal to the process's PID. If you don't run `setsid`, there will be no process group for `killpg` to send to (hence the error).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set process group using `os.setpgrp()` before calling `os.killpg()`.
If you don't set any process group then you won't be able to kill it using `os.killpg()`

You can create process group using following ways:

1. `os.setpgrp()` -- If no argument is passed then it is equivalent to os.setpgrp(0,0). This will create a process group with id same as the calling process id.
2. `os.setpgrp(0, 999)` -- It will create a process group with id 999 and the current process will be part of that group. You can use any process id instead of 0 to make it part of that process group.

`os.setpgrp()` actually calls linux system call `setpgrp()`. See following linux man page for detail:
https://linux.die.net/man/2/setpgrp

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and following the recommendations [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true/4791612#4791612) I fixed it by adding `preexec_fn=os.setsid` to the Popen call this way the created processes form a new process group and all the children it creates later belongs to this same session. This way you can kill the process and its children by calling `os.killpg` on the created process session id.

For example you can create your process as following:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('sleep  53 & sleep  54 | sleep  56', shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
... do whatever ..
os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```